# android sdk on ubuntu Starting emulator for AVD PANIC: Could not open:

Tags: android, ubuntu

I found tons of answers to this question for Windows, but my problem is on linux (ubuntu). I just downloaded the adt bundle, launched eclipse and tried to start an emulator from the Virtual Device Manager, but I am getting the message

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AS'
PANIC: Could not open: AS
```

I tried to run both as root or not root without success.

Thanks

Comment: I think it belongs to http://superuser.com/ or maybe http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

Dont use ./emulator -avd {AVD NAME} as a super user...Try using it without root it worked for me..for more details see this [link](http://rafeebuet.blogspot.in/2012/05/can-not-start-avd-after-creating.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  Turns out I didn't have proper permissions on my `Eclipse ADT Bundle`.

Try:

```
sudo chown -R username adt-bundle-linux-x86_64****
```

Make sure you have permissions on your workspace too...

```
sudo chown -R username Workspace
```

Then you should be able to launch Eclipse as non-root and run the AVD just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

Open terminal and type the following

```
   sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

For more information check the link below

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

I guess android sdk is 32 bit so you need ia32-libs if you are running on 64 bit machine

Edit:

You can try this

open terminal

and type

```
  sudo chmod -R 777 'YOURPATH of sdk folder(Just Drag and Drop your Android sdk folder here)'
```

This will give read write and execute permission

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that without success. ia32-libs is already the newest version.

Comment: is your machine 64 bit? this worked for me i have ubuntu and i could start the emulator after installing ia32-libs

Comment: machine is 64 bit. I also tried the chmod but it doesn't help. I just noticed that I skipped step 2 of the installation ( Installing the Eclipse Plugin). Will give it a try and post here the result.

Comment: Still no luck. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you could try piecemeal install

eclipse download - no bundle

sdk download install

[adt](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

I use ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse 4.3 and all is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Android Emulator Problem [Solved]

The issue with android emulator is not the hardware drivers. It is OpenGL drivers. To solve it please go through these steps:

1. Open synaptic package manager (If not please install it from Ubuntu software center)
2. In Quick filter type “opengl” and press search.
3. Select the following packages: 
   libgles1-mesa-dev
   libgles2-mesa-dev
   libgles1-mesa
   libgles2-mesa
   libqt4-opengl [Update/Upgrade]
   glmark2
   glmark2-es2
   libgles1-mesa-dbg
   libgles2-mesa-dbg
   freeglut3
   libhugs-opengl-bundled
4. Selection procedure
   Right click on the package and select as ‘Mark for Installation”.
5. And click ‘Apply’.
6. Enjoy the ANDROID PROGRAMMING WITH THE EMULATOR.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `chown ~/.android` as well as chowning the ADK directory worked for me (ubuntu 12)